# how to split a long text file at a particular symbols and pasting the splitted files side by side

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, awk

Hii experts i want to split a large column of text file at a particular symbol(here >) and want to paste the splitted file side by side as given in a example below:

I tried with `split -l 4 inputfile > otputfile` but it doesnot help.I hope some expert will definitely help me.

For example i have data as given below:

```
>
1
2
2
4
>
4
3
5
3
>
4
5
2
3
```

and i need output like as below

```
1 4 4
2 3 5
2 5 2
4 3 3
```

Comment: There is no "splitting" here (ie. "split" as in cut one file into multiple parts and save them into _multiple files_). There are no multiple files, it looks like you want to change _one_ file into _another one single_ file. You want to reformat your data. Write an `awk` script - read lines into an array, then when `>` is encoutered, reset an index into that array and append the data. There are many `awk` tutorials on the web, be sure to check them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment lines between `>` mark may not be regular in numbers if this is the case I have come up with following, where it will add `NA` for missing specific occurrence of `>`. Written and tested with GNU `awk` and considering no empty lines in your Input_file here.

```
awk -v RS=">" -v FS="\n" '
FNR==NR{
  max=(max>NF?max:NF)
  next
}
FNR>1{
  for(i=2;i<max;i++){
    val[i]=(val[i]?val[i] OFS:"")($i?$i:"NA")
  }
}
END{
  for(i=2;i<max;i++){
    print val[i]
  }
}' Input_file Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/^>/{
  count=""
  next
}
{
  ++count
  val[count]=(val[count]?val[count] OFS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
   print val[i]
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                               ##Starting awk program from here.
/^>/{                                               ##Checking condition if a line starts from > then do following.
  count=""                                          ##Nullifying count variable here.
  next                                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  ++count                                           ##Incrementing count variable with 1 here.
  val[count]=(val[count]?val[count] OFS:"")$0       ##Creating val with index count and keep adding current lines values to it with spaces.
}
END{                                                ##Starting END block for this awk program from here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){                            ##Starting a for loop from here.
   print val[i]                                     ##Printing array val with index i here.
  }
}' Input_file                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: it works fine for even data sets.  if the data length is different  in between >... > it doesnot work

Comment: @sion, solutions on SO are given as per shown samples only, it was not mentioned in question. Let me do a tweak to code now and let you know here.

Comment: @sion, how about `awk '/^>/{max=count>max?count:max;count="";next} {++count;val[count]=(val[count]?val[count] OFS:"")$0} END{for(i=1;i<=max;i++){print val[i]?val[i]:0}}'  Input_file` one? This will cover all elements, this should do the trick kindly do let me know on same.

Comment: it works...but the extralength data are concatenated on the first column only not below its respective column.

Comment: @sion, ok fixed it with some test samples, try `awk -v RS=">" -v FS="\n" 'FNR==NR{max=max>NF?max:NF;next} FNR>1{for(i=2;i<max;i++){val[i]=(val[i]?val[i] OFS:"")($i?$i:"NA")}} END{for(i=1;i<=max;i++){if(val[i]){print val[i]}}}'  Input_file  Input_file` reading `Input_file` 2 times here, it will add `NA` to fields which are NOT found, let me know how it goes?

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh for your hard work, It works fine...

Answer (score 1):

A Python solution as you tagged Python:

```py
columns = []  # List of columns, each column will be another list of lines
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()  # Remove leading and trailing white spaces like "\n"
        if line == '>':
            columns.append([])  # If we find a ">" append a new column
        else:
            columns[-1].append(line)  # else append the line to the last column

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in zip(*columns):  # zip(*columns) trasposes the matrix
        f.write(" ".join(row) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below program

```py
a=""">
1
2
2
4
>
4
3
5
3
>
4
5
2
3"""
res=[[c for c in b.split("\n") if c] for b in a.split(">") if b]
print("\n".join([" ".join([item[i] for item in res]) for i in range(len(res[0]))]))
```

**Output**

```
1 4 4
2 3 5
2 5 2
4 3 3
```

---

If you want to read from file. use this program as below.
This produces same output as above.

```py
with open("input.txt","r") as f, open("output.txt","w") as f1:
    a=f.read()
    res=[[c for c in b.split("\n") if c] for b in a.split(">") if b]
    f1.write("\n".join([" ".join([item[i] for item in res]) for i in range(len(res[0]))]))
```

Comment: This solution writes an extra space at the end of each line

Comment: its also a nice solution...but manually writing the whole input  column is not possible

Comment: I have updated the program for file reading. please check